# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.app.persistence.Test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am running a Spring Boot Project where I want to use Hibernate and HQL queries.

I am getting following error:

```
Exception in Dao
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.app.persistence.Test
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:783)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1520)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:679)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:671)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:666)
    at com.thp.clinic.allergiesConditions.dao.AllergiesDaoImpl.check(AllergiesDaoImpl.java:38)
    at com.thp.clinic.allergiesConditions.dao.AllergiesDaoImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$6b8d942f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.thp.clinic.allergiesConditions.dao.AllergiesDaoImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$b9677149.check(<generated>)
    at com.thp.clinic.allergiesConditions.service.AllergiesServiceImpl.check(AllergiesServiceImpl.java:23)
    at com.thp.clinic.allergiesConditions.service.AllergiesServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7070308f.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at com.thp.clinic.allergiesConditions.service.AllergiesServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1fddf4a.check(<generated>)
    at com.thp.clinic.allergiesConditions.controller.AllergiesController.check(AllergiesController.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
```

My Model class is as follows:

```
package com.app.persistence;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class Test {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="test_id")
    private long testId;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="phone")
    private String phone;

    //getters and setters
}
```

And my DAO is as follows:

```
@Autowired 
    SessionFactory factory;

    @Override
    public String check(Test test) {
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = factory.openSession();
            session.save(test);
            session.flush();
            return "done";
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in Dao");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
```

I understand that it is not able to map with the model class. But I am not able to figure out where I should add the mapping (if required).

I have already included `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app" })` in my configuration class.

Can someone please help me to sort it out?

Comment: `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app" })` is for components. Make sure you set your `@EntityScan` annotation pointing to your entity class package

Comment: Have you used `@EntityScan` ? The `@EntityScan` is used to scan your entity packages. `@ComponentScan` annotation is used to create beans for every class annotated with @Component, @Service, @Controller, @RestController, @Repository, ... and registers them to the Spring container

Comment: @Hiren Thanks for reply. Can you please also tell where exactly should i add `@EntityScan`??

Comment: you can add it in your configuration file (i.e file annotated with `@Configuration`) generally same place where `@ComponentScan` is used. add `@EntityScan(basePackages = { "youentitypackage" })`.

Comment: @Hiren Thanks, It helped!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `@EntityScan(basePackages = { "youentitypackage" })` along with `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.app" })`. This will look for your entity classes.

Comment: Thanks, Though it was simple enough, but sometimes may be difficult to figure out for beginners :)

Comment: yeah! would be helpful when someone else run to same error :) happy yo help